# Postgresql query to return filtered result

Tags: sql, postgresql

My query

```
    select link.id, bti_status.bti_status from link
inner join bti
    on link.id = bti.id
inner join bti_status
    on bti.id = bti_status.bti_id
```

returns the following table.

[image]

I would like that query, returns only the set of id's which don't have bti_status = 4, so no id = 403, in any of the rows, should be returned because row 5 has an bti_status value of 4.

I've tried the following query but I'm not sure if it does the work correctly.

```
    select link.id, bti_status.bti_status from link
inner join bti
    on link.id = bti.id
inner join bti_status
    on bti.id = bti_status.bti_id
where not exists (select bti_status from bti_status where bti_status = 4);
```

**UPDATE**

Regarding @GMB answer my original query is actually different than the one I posted. Original query is

```
select link.id, bti_status.bti_status, bti.id from link
inner join bti_link
    on link.id = bti_link.id
inner join bti
    on bti_link.bti_id = bti.id
inner join deadline
    on deadline.id = link.deadline_id
inner join bti_status
    on bti.id = bti_status.bti_id
where deadline.id = :id
and not exists (select bti_status from bti_status where bti_status = 4);
```

and if I try yours solution I can't get it to work

```
select l.id, bs.bti_status, b.id 
from (
        select l.id, bs.bti_status, b.id, 
            bool_or(bs.bti_status = 4) over(partition by l.id) has_status_4
        from link l
        inner join bti_link on l.id = bti_link.id
        inner join bti b on bti_link.bti_id = b.id
        inner join deadline d on d.id = l.deadline_id
        inner join bti_status bs on b.id = bs.bti_id
) t
where d.id = :id
and not has_status_4;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as GMB said, window function is one way.

you can also use CTE:

```
WITH data AS (
   SELECT link.id AS link_id, bti_status.bti_status, bti.id AS bti_id
   FROM link
   INNER JOIN bti_link ON link.id = bti_link.id
   INNER JOIN bti ON bti_link.bti_id = bti.id
   INNER JOIN deadline ON deadline.id = link.deadline_id
   INNER JOIN bti_status ON bti.id = bti_status.bti_id
   WHERE deadline.id = :id
   )
SELECT * 
FROM data
WHERE link_id NOT IN (
   SELECT link_id 
   FROM data 
   WHERE bti_status = 4)
```

Comment: I can't get it to work. i get an error saying "SQL Error [42702]: ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous
  Position: 376
  ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous
  Position: 376
  ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous
  Position: 376"

Comment: I edited column names. try now.  the original query had two columns named id.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with window functions. Here is one way to do it using boolean window aggregation:

```
select id, bti_status
from (
    select l.id, bs.bti_status, 
        bool_or(bs.bti_status = 4) over(partition by l.id) has_status_4
    from link l
    inner join bti b on l.id = b.id
    inner join bti_status bs on b.id = bs.bti_id
) t
where not has_status_4
```

Comment: @Marko: remove the `l`, `bs` and `d` prefixes in the outer `select` clause (or use `t` everywhere): they are not defined in this scope. So: `select id, bti_status  from (...) t where id = :id and not has_status_4`. Also you have two columns called `id` in the subquery, this is ambigious. You need to alias at least one of them.

Comment: When I do that I get "SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "link"
  Position: 8
  ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "link"
  Position: 8
  ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "link"
  Position: 8"